# Change app to only iPhone deployment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, deployment, device

Im using Xcode 4.1 lion release. My app was rejected because it only works on the iPhone, this is how it should be, but i guess i didnt set my app up so it only works on the iPhone. How would i do so?

I go to Targeted Device Family under my project build settings and i have `iPhone` selected. 
`
What else do i need to do. Thanks

EDIT: During the app review it was still set up under device family as iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove and iPad xib files that were created initially. By default Xcode makes an iPad folder when you select the universal build, remove that and you should be good. Other considerations might be to remove iPad launch images if they are present, or any iPad specific code like popover view controllers etc.